# Noether's Theorem proof

Tags: physics, proof-explanation, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

Here is the proof of Noether's Theorem given in Peskin's and Schroeder's book on QFT:

[image]
[image]

What I don't understand is why he writes that $\Delta \mathcal{L} = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}\Delta\phi + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\Delta(\partial_\mu\phi)$. I do not see why these $\Delta$ should be small enough so that we could do something like $\Delta f=f'\Delta x$.

Comment: The use of $\phi' = \phi + \alpha\Delta\phi$ is perhaps a bit confusing here. The variation of the field $\phi$ is $\alpha\Delta\phi$ (not just $\Delta\phi$) and the smallness of $\alpha$ is what ensures this is valid.

Comment: @Winther Still, I do not see why $\alpha$ should be "small": if the Lagrangian is of the form 2.10, then the transformation is a symmetry of the theory, regardless of the value of $\alpha$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: What do you mean by "if the Lagrangian is of the form 2.10"? (2.10) gives no information about the Lagrangian, it simply dictates the transformation properties that we need for it to satisfy under $\phi \to \phi + \alpha \Delta \phi$.

Comment: @Winther Yes, maybe I should have said "If the Lagrangian transforms as in (2.10)"

Comment: (2.10) is really nothing but the definition of what we meant by a symmetry and in this definition $\alpha$ is often assumed to be "infinitesimal". Why only consider infinitesimal transformations then? Very roughly speaking, we can make any finite transformation by performing "a lot" of infinitesimal transformations so it's only necessary to consider the infinitesimal ones. This is handy as infinitesimal transformations are much easier to study as it allows us to use well known tools as Taylor expansions etc.